# При выполнении EXECUTE IMMEDIATE внутри dbms_parallel_execute появляется ошибка PLS-00103

Tags: база-данных, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Столкнулся с такой задачей: необходимо распараллелить процесс внутри БД Oracle 12c. Начал делать, как обычно, через пакет `dbms_parallel_execute`. Создаю задание через процедуру `dbms_parallel_execute.run_task`, в качестве параметра `sql_stmt` передаю `VARCHAR2` с анонимным блоком, который вызывает мою хранимую процедуру. В свою очередь, эта процедура вызывает еще несколько других процедур.

В результате, моя "родительская" процедура падает с ошибкой.

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "." to continue.
```

Как я выяснил, это связано с тем, что в одной из вызываемых процедур есть конструкция:

```
l_sql := 'BEGIN ' || get_package || '.some_procedure(:1, :2); END;'

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql 
USING l_param_1, l_param_2l
```

Когда я заменил ее на прямой вызов, моя процедура стала работать нормально. Но, к сожалению, я не могу убрать эту конструкцию на целевой среде.

Есть какие-нибудь обходные пути, чтобы исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Добейтесь чтобы  фун-я get_package возращала то, что от неё ожидается (судя по имени,  имя пакета). Судя по ошибке, она возвращает null. А что такое _прямой вызов_?

Comment: @0xdb, да, действительно проблема оказалось в этом. Значение инициализируется в начале сессии, а я открываю множество других. Выпало почему-то из головы, как работает эта функция. Извиняюсь за беспокойство. Можете написать ответ, чтобы я принял его?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `get_package` возвращает `NULL`. То есть во время выполнения получится конструкция, которая синтаксически неверна:

```
l_sql := 'BEGIN .some_procedure(:1, :2); END;'
               ^^^
```

что и приводит к указанной в вопросе ошибке.